# How to create a multiple choice answer sheet in word? (the fastest and easiest method)

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to achieve something like this picture in word 2016:

[image: multiple choice answer sheet]

I want the "a" "b" and etc to be inside those squares.

What is the easiest and fastest way to do that?

---

I also want to create another file which should look like this:

[image: multiple choice answer sheet with correct answers marked]

How can I fill the inside of those squares as shown in the picture with black color?

Comment: Use a table....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to achieve this, It's hard to say which is best without more information - here's two options...

1. Use a table in word, fill in the left most column with the question numbers manually then add "a" to "x" in the other cells. Manually set the background colour to black and the text colour to white on the cells you require.
2. If you already have a list of question numbers and the correct answer (a,b,c etc...) then do it in excel using conditional formatting to highlight the correct answer. Then just copy and paste into word.

If I had to do this, I would do it via option 2 - but I have experience in excel and scripting. I guess you need to weigh up the time involved trying to do it manually vs the time it will take you to work out custom formatting and potentially H or V Lookup in excel.

Comment: That was absolutely brilliant!